# Scrolling in grid control under Tab Item in Wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

**C# WPF**: I'm trying to put a simple scroll bar around my grid. The grid is a tab item. I am enclosing the grid with scrollViewer and have made it visible just for checking, although i too prefer auto. But the scrollbar is not functioning. 
What I want is: whole thing is not getting accommodated on my laptop screen so the horizontal scroll should allow me to see the other parts. whole thing is enclosed in a grid so i guess putting it under scrollviewer tag made sense. Somebody please help me.

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  >
                <TabItem Name="AssessTab" Header="Assess" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="Green" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <Grid Height="Auto" Name="StackPanel1" Width="Auto" ClipToBounds="True">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="29" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="70*" MinHeight="200" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="56" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1043"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="156*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Content="Count All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,5,0,3.8" Name="CountAllProjectsButton" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="CountAllProjectsButton_Click" ToolTip="Scan the petrel project and populate the objects count."/>
                                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PetrelSummaryGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" MinWidth="150" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AlternationCount="2" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" AutoGeneratingColumn="PetrelSummaryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
                                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Check All" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                            <MenuItem Header="UnCheck All" Click="MenuItem_Click_1" />
                                            <MenuItem Header="Check Selected"  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" Click="MenuItem_Click_2"/>
                                            <MenuItem Header="UnCheck Selected"  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" Click="MenuItem_Click_2"/>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Copy WKT" Tag="SK" Click="MenuItem_Click_4" />
                                            <MenuItem Header="Copy Petrel WKT" Tag="PETREL" Click="MenuItem_Click_4" />
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsError}" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.8"/>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                </DataGrid>
                                <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,1" Name="gridSplitter7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="8" />
                                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="gridSplitter5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="8" />
                                <tk:DataGrid Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="4" FrozenColumnCount="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Name="AssessmentGrid" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader">
                                    <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Feature" Binding="{Binding Path=Feature, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Binding="{Binding Path=Duration, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}\{0:F\}}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Units" Binding="{Binding Path=Units, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Minutes" Binding="{Binding Path=Minutes, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Days" Binding="{Binding Path=Days, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}\{0:F\}}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                </tk:DataGrid>
                                <Button Content="Cancel Count" x:Name="CancelCountButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="CancelCountButton_Click"/>
                                <Button Content="Save Assessment " Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,5,0,0" Name="SaveAssessmentButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Click="SaveAssessmentButton_Click" ToolTip="Save the Assesment to XML for future use."/>
                                <Label Name="lblAssessVisualIndicator" Content="!" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="135,0,0,5" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Visibility="Visible" ToolTip="Unsaved data present in the assesment grid."/>
                                <Button Content="Load Assessment" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,4,0,0" Name="LoadAssessmentButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="True" Click="LoadAssessmentButton_Click" ToolTip="Load previosely saved assesment."/>
                                <ProgressBar Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="35,0,11,4" Name="prgBarAsses" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                <Label Content="Progress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,0,0,4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.484,0" Width="73" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="2" />
                            </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </TabItem>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the scroll bars but they are not working

Comment: then you able to see only the scrollviewer?

Comment: Your problem is the size of your TabControl. You have to make sure that the TabControl doesn't grow in infinite. When the TabControl stops growing the ScrollViewer will work as it shoud.